# vpn connection is OK but can't route some IPs

Tags: cisco-asa, cisco-vpn

Our Network is laid out as in the diagram below

[image: Network Diagram]

PC1 can successfully connect to server 2 (with  10.120.20.x/24), and
PC4 can successfully connect to server 1 (with  10.120.30.x/24).

Our problem is that the PC on the right hand side (with IP = 10.254.11.18) cannot connect to server 1.  Unfortunately I cannot change the IP of this PC (10.254.11.18)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: :)
sorry i mean advice from others.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. You want the PC on the right side of the router to communicate with the server on the left of the router?

Comment: Yes.
I want to connect the red one to left side of server(server 1) through vpn

Comment: Do I only need to check only right side of router configuration?

Comment: The router on the right needs to have an ip address in the same network as the PC (10.254.11.x). How to do that is specific to the router. It might be as simple as assigning an additional ip address to the router or adding a sub-interface to the router. Then the router on the left needs a routing table entry to tell it that it can reach the PC (10.254.11.x) through the router on the right.

Comment: Yes the router on the right is in DC and the red PC is from company.
Actually does i need to try  assign an additional ip address to the router?

Answer (score 0):

The PC that is not working (10.254.11.18) is not in the same IP range as the others on the right hand side's subnet (I'm assuming that the subnet is defined as 10.120.30.0/4).

If you really can't change that IP (which sounds rather odd), then you will need a subnet that includes that IP, which means your AS5505 router will need an IP in that range (e.g. 10.254.11.0/0), and associated routing table entries, and also your AS5520 will need to know to route that subnet to your AS5505.  Your AS5505 could advertise that it handles that subnet range, but depending how complex the bits of your network you're not showing us are already, a static routing entry might be simpler.

Why can't you modify the 10.254.11.18 IP?  How is it being assigned at present?  I'm guessing that this involved its participation in some network structure you're not telling us about, which might substantially modify what I should be telling you about your routing issues.

Comment: I did miss the router model. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Thanks you, mc0e and joeqwerty
Yes, the PC is not in IP range.
And 10.254.11.18 cannot change because the others applications depend on this.
Thanks you very much.